# Not inserting values to database when data is similar

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a payroll system. The admin is able to successfully save these [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f5Ok.jpg) but when an employee ID, which is already in the database, is selected, it is not added to the database. Here is my code:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO payroll VALUES('$id','$period','$paidDays','$hourlyRate','$hoursworked','$overtime','$overtimePay','$undertime','undertimePay','$sss','$philHealth','$pagibig','$OtherDeductions','$tax','$grossPay','$netPay')";`

I need to solve this to be able to do the Salary History of the employees.

PLEASE NOTE that this code is working. It's just that when a similar employee is inputted, it is not added to the database. Thanks!

**EDITED:** THIS is the [table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bBNC.jpg)

Comment: And you'd like it to be added to the database? or are you intending to avoid that?

Comment: @Sina, I believe she wants to add to database since he wants to have "Salary History". By any chance you made that column "Unique index" ?

Comment: Hi Sina! Yes, it should be added to the database.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, I did not make it unique

Comment: can you post your table structure

Comment: `id` is primary key?

Comment: if id is primary key and if u try to add same data again it wont insert because it conflicts, id can have only unique values. so if u trying to add same values, i think u can go for update query. or else just change id value, rest as same.

Comment: I did not set anything else to ID, just the INT and the value of 10

Comment: by seeing ur table structure, it looks like ur id is primary key

Comment: I dropped the primary key by executing this code 'ALTER TABLE people1
DROP PRIMARY KEY'. I did not know I have a primary key then since this payroll system is a group project. Looks like my member made it a primary key. Haha! **Thanks guys!**

Comment: If the solution to your problem is dropping the primary key from your table, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your table structure, Id must be **PRIMARY KEY** that is why it can't be added when you select an existing id. 
As primary key can not be duplicated, so if you want to have that process, the structure have to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that '....similiar employee...' is defined by ID, and this might give you a hints :

```
 Insert Into Payroll
 Select id,period,paidDays,hourlyRate,hoursworked, overtime,overtimePay,
 undertime,undertimePay,sss,philHealth,pagibig,OtherDeductions,
 tax,grossPay,netPay
 FROM (
 select '$id' AS ID,'$period' AS period,'$paidDays' AS  paidDays,
 '$hourlyRate' AS hourlyRate, '$hoursworked' AS hoursworked,
 '$overtime' AS overtime,'$overtimePay' AS overtimePay,
 '$undertime' AS undertime,'undertimePay' AS undertimePay,
 '$sss' AS sss,'$philHealth' AS philHealth,'$pagibig' AS pagibig,
 '$OtherDeductions' AS OtherDeductions,'$tax' AS tax,
 '$grossPay' AS grossPay,'$netPay' AS netPay, 0 AS JUM
  UNION ALL
  select id,period,paidDays,hourlyRate,hoursworked,  overtime,
  overtimePay, undertime,undertimePay,sss,philHealth,pagibig,
  OtherDeductions,tax,grossPay,netPay, 1 AS JUM
  from [YourTable]
  Where [ID] = [EmployeeID]) AS T
  GROUP BY id,period,paidDays,hourlyRate,hoursworked, overtime,
  overtimePay, undertime,undertimePay,sss,philHealth,pagibig,
  OtherDeductions,tax,grossPay,netPay
  HAVING SUM(JUM) <0
```